# Does scripture allow for "speaking in tongues" to be in non-human languages?

Tags: spiritual-gifts, language, tongue

"Tongues" is a metonym for "language".

In **1 Corinthians 13:1** Paul says:

> Though I speak with the tongues of men and of angels … (KJV)
>
> If I could speak all the languages of earth and of angels … (NLT throughout)

The KJV possibly implies that some people might also speak in the non-human language of angels.
(*This complicates the issue, and I don't personally believe that Paul meant it literally, but I'll include the possibility in what follows. I would though prefer an answer that simply ignores this possibility.*)

**Acts 2** describes when the disciples first "spoke in tongues":

> <sup>**4**</sup> And everyone present was filled with the Holy Spirit and began speaking in other languages, as the Holy Spirit gave them this ability.
>
> <sup>**11**</sup> … And we all hear these people speaking in our own languages about the wonderful things God has done!

This clearly shows an ability to temporarily speak to others in their own language.

In **1 Corinthians 14** Paul talks about this ability, discouraging its use when there is no one that can understand the foreign language.

> <sup>**9**</sup> It’s the same for you. If you speak to people in words they don’t understand, how will they know what you are saying? You might as well be talking into empty space.
>
> <sup>**27**</sup> No more than two or three should speak in tongues. They must speak one at a time, and someone must interpret what they say.
> <sup>**28**</sup>But if no one is present who can interpret, they must be silent in your church meeting and speak in tongues to God privately.

It might be possible that the speaker is sometimes not able to understand what he himself is saying (except of course if it is the language of angels), otherwise why use an interpreter when the speaker could repeat it themself.

So unless there is someone present that *can* understand it but can't understand the common language, using this gift is pointless and annoying, not to mention being a case of showing off.

This also implies that one needs to consciously control this gift to ensure that it is used only when it would be useful.

To me, this seems to say that the languages are either human (to be spoken only when some human can understand that language and not the speaker's normal language) or angelic (to be spoken only to God, and not in the presence of other people).

The question is, **is there anything in scripture that even implies that the language could be anything else (neither human nor angelic), or that it should ever be spoken in situations where no human listener can understand it?**.

Comment: I am struggling to understand precisely what you are asking here.

Comment: @Dottard, I'm asking if there is any biblical basis for the current practice of "speaking in tongues", where people utter what sounds like gibberish and is definitely not any known language (as opposed to speaking in say Mandarin, which neither the speaker nor anyone in the room understands).

Comment: @Dottard, I'm thinking perhaps I got my logic backward and should have reworded it and asked it on the other site.

Comment: That question is essentially the same as asking whether the tongues in Acts 2 (understandable languages) is the same as the tongues in 1 Cor 13 and 14.  That question has been asked on this site a few times.  See https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A33540+tongues

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does 1 Corinthians 13:1 indicate the existence of ‘angelic’ languages?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/55525/does-1-corinthians-131-indicate-the-existence-of-angelic-languages)

Comment: @Michael16, thanks, but no. I really seem to be having trouble communicating what my actual question is. If it didn't have answers, I'd delete this question.

Comment: My answer in that question covers the issue of understandability of the angelic languages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is praying in tongues to God in a private setting scripturally supported by 1 Corinthians 14:2?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/54214/is-praying-in-tongues-to-god-in-a-private-setting-scripturally-supported-by-1-co)

Comment: @Dottard, no, it's more like the complement of what I wanted. ¶ I just moved a misplaced parenthesis in my final sentence and realized that it still doesn't make sense, even to me. So I rewrote it again.

Comment: So like, Binary? Python? Perl? Java? C++? What does non-human mean in this context? Speaking whale? Are you assuming the existence of extraterrestrial life?

Answer (score 4):

Paul, in chapter thirteen, is making an extreme case to illustrate a point. Likely drawing on the notion that some human languages are more eloquent than others, he write that not even the eloquence of a celestial being is of any value if the speech being made is not motivated by love.

There is no need to conclude that the "tongues of angels" is intended to apply to the passage in chapter fourteen, and the intervening text indicates that he has moved on to a related but separate topic.

In fact, the point of chapter fourteen makes the question moot. Either speak a language the hearer can understand, have an interpreter who can translate, or keep mum. There's nothing suggesting that there's an exception for angelic languages.

This is all in line with how miraculous powers were used in the early church, and how Jesus employed them during His ministry: Not only were they signs that God was behind the person doing the miracle, each and every miracle had an immediate useful effect. The lame walked, the blind saw, the leper was cleansed, the hungry was fed, etc. Speaking when I cannot be understood is simply showing off.

Are there angelic languages? Maybe. But neither an affirmative answer, nor a negative one, has any bearing on my Christian walk, so I would qualify it as one of those questions that we are advised to avoid in order to keep the peace.

Comment: I generally agree, but my real question wasn't really about the language of angels, which I'd prefer to ignore if possible. I've modified the question to make this more obvious. Sorry for not being clearer the first time. +1.

Answer (score 1):

The doctrine NT "tongues" has been considerably muddied in English because of the mis-translation of the KJV where it translates the Greek "glossa" with unwarranted "unknown tongues" in several places.  More on this shortly.

There are two broad categories of understanding about tongues:

1. Those who understand that the “tongues” in Corinthians as similar to that in Acts 2; that is, the tongues in both places were understandable human (foreign) languages.
2. Those who understand the “tongues” in 1 Corinthians 14 are different from that in Acts 2.  Such people believe in “ecstatic utterances” which are unrelated to any human language, ie, the language of angels or something else such a special heavenly language.  They have a technical name for this: glossalalia (Greek: tongues-speaking.  This word does not occur in the New Testament and thus is unbiblical.)  Many such people believe that this gift of glossalalia is the distinguishing sign of the true believer and that all believers must obtain this gift in order to receive the Holy Spirit.

[Note:  It is apparent that the translators of the King James Version took the second view because in most places where the Greek word glossa (tongue, language) occurs, they often translated it "*unknown tongue*", eg, 1 Cor 14:2, 4, 13, 14, 27.  That is, they inserted the unwarranted word, "unknown" where none exists in the Greek!  Thus many have incorrectly assumed that this reflects the original Greek text.]

In order to decide between these mutually exclusive positions it is necessary to place this question in a wider context because it involves two other issues:  the gift of the Spirit and His gifts to church members.

Jesus bequeathed the Gift of the Holy Spirit (John 20:22) to His church for several reasons:

1. To produce the fruit of the Spirit (Gal 5:22 & 23) and so to sanctify the church
2. To provide specific guidance for the church (John 16:7-13)
3. To build up the church with spiritual (supernatural) gifts (1 Cor 12:7, 14:12)
4. To teach the church more of Jesus (John 16:12-15)
   The gift of tongues is just one of these (20 or so) spiritual gifts bestowed by the Holy Spirit.  Concerning this gift of tongues, we note:

- It is just one of about twenty spiritual gifts including wisdom, knowledge, faith, healing, miracles, prophecy, distinguishing spirits, tongues, interpretation, administration, apostleship, teaching, helping, hospitality, generosity, encouragement, mercy, preaching, evangelism, etc. (1 Cor 12, 14; Rom 12:3-8; Eph 4:11-13)
- Tongues is not the greatest gift:  it is inferior to (for example) prophecy. (1 Cor 14:5 & 19)
- Tongues is nowhere described as the distinguishing mark of God's church.
- Rather, based on 1 Cor 14:22-25; Mal 4:5; Rev 12:17, 14:12; 19:10, it could be argued that one of the identifying marks of God's church is the gift of prophecy.
- Not everyone has every gift; and not everyone will be given the gift of tongues.  (1 Cor 12:10 & 28)  However, all will receive at least one gift and some will receive the gift of tongues. (1 Cor 12:7)
- Anyone who speaks in a foreign tongue must do so for the benefit of the listeners and must talk so that they understand in their own language. (1 Cor 14:5, 9, 13, 19, 28, Acts 2, etc)
- Tongues must be exercised for the strengthening of the church. (1 Cor 14:26-28)
- Tongues should be used with extreme caution. (1 Cor 14:23 & 28)
- Tongues was given to bridge language barriers. (Acts 2:4-12)
- Tongues is a sign primarily for those outside the church not those within the church. (1 Cor 14:22, 23).  This was presumably to overcome the considerable language barriers in the cosmopolitan, linguistically eclectic, Roman provinces of the first century, and many other places ever since.

The reference to "tongues of angels" is obviously Paul's hyperbole to make a rhetorical extreme point.

Thus, it appears, even from 1 Cor 14 that the "tongues" of the NT are human languages, unknown to the speaker as a special gift of the Holy Spirit.  See appendix below.

**APPENDIX - Tongues in Acts 2 are Understandable Human Languages**

The doctrine of “tongues” is first introduced in Acts 2 about which we should observe several important features.  The important and critical verse is Acts 2:6 in this passage of v1 - 13.

> Acts 2:6 - And when this sound happened, the assembled multitude was
> bewildered because they were hearing them speaking, each one, in his
> own dialect. (My translation)

But first some background.

Three times in this passage, Luke uses a variant of the same verb, πληρόω (pléroó) in several cognate forms:

1. V1, "fulfilled" συμπληροῦσθαι (symplērousthai)
2. V2, ""it filled" ἐπλήρωσεν (eplērōsen)
3. V4, "were filled" ἐπλήσθησαν (eplēsthēsan)

Three times the Holy Spirit is recorded as performing a remarkable, supernatural miracle on the assembled group of people:

1. V3, Tongues of fire "appeared"
2. V4, They began to "speak" in other languages
3. V6, They were "hearing" - each in his own dialect (and V8)

Note the important word (unique to Luke) in V6 & V8 "dialect" διαλέκτῳ (dialektō) as distinct from the word for "language" γλῶσσα (glóssa) in V4. "Dialect" here is not just the language group but the form of the language unique to each area. As Meyer's commentary observes:

> διαλέκτῳ is here also not national language, but dialect (see on Acts
> 1:19), language in its provincial peculiarity.

Thus, while V9-11 lists 16 language groups, there were probably hundreds of provincial dialects - more than the number of disciples preaching at Pentecost.

Now, the important question is this: Is the "gift of tongues" as recorded in Acts 2:1-13 a miracle of the speaker, or the miracle of the hearer, or both? Based on the above evidence, I would suggest it is BOTH. I am sure (based in 1 Cor 14, etc) that the disciples miraculously spoke other languages, see V4, V11. Equally, the hearers then heard the message proclaimed in their own provincial language dialect, V6, V8.

So Luke is quite precise in his terminology here: The speakers spoke other languages while the hearers heard their own dialects. That is, a miracle of both the speakers and the hearers.

There is a similar miracle, performed by the Holy Spirit, recorded in Rom 8:26 where He (the Holy Spirit) translates the language that a Christian petitioner asks of God:

> In the same way the Spirit also helps our weakness; for we do not know
> how to pray as we should, but the Spirit Himself intercedes for us
> with groanings too deep for words;

Thus, the miracle of Pentecost is not unique; nor is it beyond the power of omnipotence.

Comment: Nice, well researched.  +1 from me.  Aside, glossalalia is not unique to Christian faith.  It elsewhere features in many cultures via ecstatic states of ritual, is shown not to follow meaningful linguistic constructs, and uses speech elements from the native language(s) of the speaker.

Comment: @Thermion - great comment!

Answer (score 0):

When we read 1 Corinthians chapters 12-14 as one topic and consider the reason why Paul wrote this letter, we may conclude that Paul was using a subtle hyperbole to suggest that those who spoke in angelic language were liars who pretended to process a special spiritual gift.

Paul wrote the letter in response to the letter from Chloe's household who reported there were quarrels among the Church, resulting in division in them (1 Corinthians 1:11-12). One quarrel was spiritual gifts, which Paul briefly mentioned in 1:7, and detailed in chapters 12-14.

The prime message in chapter 12 is the church need to be united in one Spirit, for all kinds of spiritual gift is given by the same Spirit (12:4), and each member will receive a different gift, as if the different parts of a body (church), *'so that there should be no division in the body, but that its parts should have equal concern for each other.' (12:25).*

In chapter 13, Paul put his audience focus on 'LOVE'. For all kinds of Spiritual Gift without Love are nothing (13:1-3). Paul concluded: "Love never ends (or fails)" but Spiritual Gifts (prophesy, tongues, knowledge) will cease (13:8) when the Lord returns (13:10).

In chapter 14, Paul explained what are true spiritual gifts and how these gifts can be testified.

Regarding the question about those who speak angelic language, Paul wrote;

- they only speak to God for no one understands them (14:2)
- they edify themselves (14:4)
- unless someone interprets, the church may not be edified (14:5)
- if Paul spoke to them in tongues, he did no good to them (14:6)
- if no one understands the language, it is just speaking into the air (14:9)
- all languages have their meaning (14:10)
- without a mutual understanding of the language, both will treat the other as foreigners (14:11)

Then Paul said in 1 Corinthians 14:13 NIV

> For this reason the one who speaks in a tongue should pray that they may interpret what they say.

It is worth noting that Paul did not assert or discern the existence of angelic language in these chapters. His primary concern was those who claimed to possess this spiritual gift were genuine, especially if it only edified themselves and not the church. The arguments over which spiritual gift was the greatest became one of the causes of division among the Corinthians. In 1 Corinthians 14:4-5, he said;

> <sup>**4**</sup>  Anyone who speaks in a tongue edifies themselves, but the one who prophesies edifies the church. <sup>**5**</sup>  I would like every one of you to speak in tongues, but I would rather have you prophesy. **The one who prophesies is greater than the one who speaks in tongues, unless someone interprets, so that the church may be edified.** (NIV)

Paul's main objective was to unite them in Christ and His Love, for when the Lord returns, only His Love will prevail and spiritual gifts will cease (1 Corinthians 13:8-10)

> <sup>**8**</sup>  **Love never fails**. But where there are prophecies, they will cease; where there are tongues, they will be stilled; where there is knowledge, it will pass away. <sup>**95**</sup>  For we know in part and we prophesy in part, <sup>**10**</sup>  **but when completeness comes, what is in part disappears.** (NIV)

Comment: That was quick, here you are already. I, myself, can't comment one way or another on this topic of *speaking in tongues*, as I don't believe that it has been done *genuinely* since the 1st Century apostles. Consequently I'm not prepared to vote, or comment further on same, for that would just be insincere.

Comment: @OldeEnglish - your comment is enlightening. I think I should make my words more neutral and open more space for thinking. See my edit.

Comment: Good for you on the edit. But the Q., centers around the aspect of *speaking in tongues*. What you have laid out here, whether it be on point or not, goes beyond the Q.

Comment: @OldeEnglish - you are right. I am always focus on the comprehension of the whole context, rarely separate an element for discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Many Pentecostals believe that certain types of tongues-speaking are indeed "angelic" or "non-human" in character, though perhaps "super-human" would be a better term. For example revivalist minister [Jamie Galloway](https://www.destinyimage.com/blog/jamie-galloway-angelic-tongues-understanding-the-language-of-angels) says:

> The secret of the tongues of angels empowers you to speak directly to
> God, communing with Him in the spirit over the mysteries of God. It
> calls us to join in with Heaven’s choir and sing as one voice.

He cites Revelation 5:11, where the elders of Israel join with the angels to sing  God's praise, in support:

> Then I looked, and I heard the
> voice of many angels around the throne, the living creatures, and the
> elders; and the number of them was ten thousand times ten thousand,
> and thousands of thousands...

In this interpretation tongues and humans share a language, so it is not "non-human" but the language humans and angels use in the spiritual realm. Other Pentecostal teachers cite 1 Corinthians:

> For he who speaks in a tongue does not speak to men, but to God.
> Indeed, no one understands him; he utters mysteries in the Spirit. (1
> Cor 14:2)

It is argued here that "uttering mysteries in the spirit" means that an interpretation of the tongues in this case is unnecessary, for if they were interpreted they would not be mysteries. One sings from his or her soul in an unearthly, mysterious language. [Other Pentecostals](https://www.christiantruthcenter.com/the-3-types-of-tongues-speaking-in-tongues/), however, teach that this kind of speaking in tongues should only be done in private, not in church.

**Conclusions**: It is a matter of opinion whether the above mentioned scriptural references are valid. However it has been shown here that there are indeed scriptures that Pentecostals believe support their belief that tongues-speaking is sometimes an angelic or super-human language. For those who practice this kind of tongues-speaking in church, it is neither "annoying" nor "pointless" as the OP suggests. Rather, for these congregations, it is a joyous participation the heavenly choir and a foretaste of heaven itself.

Comment: It's good that you referenced **Rev 5:11** but I would have you note my *first* comment to @Vincent Wong.